# Post category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hy,

How use **post_category** for all category and subcategory in wordpress in **wp_insert_post**?

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like an array:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'category-name' ) );
while( $query->have_posts() ); $query->the_post();

      //show your post here.

endwhile;
```

Comment: array(8,39) show only categories with IDs 8 and 39. Can not display them all without putting IDs?

Comment: Actually, `wp_insert_post` is used to insert posts into the database, not to query them out of the database. Are you looking how to query a category instead?